# Best and Secure Approach for Maintaining Login Until User Logout or Uninstall App

Tags: android

We have a working website and now developing android application. Some API calls are public however some api calls requires valid user. One server side it is being maintained through sessions and cookies. How can I communicate with server securely from app. I want that user login once until user press logout or uninstall the app. I don't want to store user username and password in app because it can be easily access by anyone if device is rooted and also I don't have password if user is using facebook login method. What should I do to in app and on server side to make it secure and easy. I think apps like facebook etc use those type of approaches in their apps which I am searching.

I have done research on this and found only that I should use static `HttpClient`.

I am using `volley library` for network calls because it suites me.

Answer (score 3):

You use a token.  When the user logs in (over an HTTPS webservice), he sends up his username and password.  The server stores that in a database and returns a token, just like a cookie would.  All future requests from the app to the webservice should be done over HTTPS and should have that token as one of the parameters.  The server can then lookup who it assigned that token to in its database, and send the user the appropriate data.  If the token isn't there or isn't in the db, you return an error.  When the user logs out, you delete the token from the DB.

The token number space needs to be big enough that a random token can't be guessed.  Using a second piece of data on each request (such as user name, or something identifying the phone such as ANDROID_ID) would help prevent guessing attacks.  And of course if you get repeated requests from someone with bad tokens you should treat that as an attack, just like you would with bad cookies.

Comment: Yes. I was also thinking something like this. However want to know some other methods as well for knowledge and discussion with web app developer. By the way thanks @Gabe Sechan

Comment: @Ali what did you mean by became invalid? It will be stored until user don't logout.

Comment: @Ali if you wanted to invalidate the token after a period of time, you could.  The web service would respond with a timeout response, which would tell the app to re-request the username and password.  It's not necessary to timeout the token, but it is more secure.